# Sencha Touch + PhoneGAP Build - iOS App rejected because of Storage setting

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

Experts,

Recently I've used PhoneGAP Build service for my iOS App (HTML5 App built using Sencha Touch), and when i submit to app store, they rejected my app with this reason

> in particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
> app stores non user-generated content in iCloud backup directories. To
> check how much data your app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage

Is there any solution?
please help

I already have this app published in BB and Android with out any issues.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pavan.cinetalk
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/32189889/

Comment: How are you storing your data? Are you using localStorage?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes i'm using 1 store with localstorage and it will get some data and store in localstorage

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry ignore my previous comment, I'm not storing any localstorage, just i'm using proxy and no offline storage or sync()

Answer (score 2):

I think PhoneGap Build might be setting BackupWebStorage by default to iCloud, if you set up PhoneGap locally this setting can be changed in the Cordova.plist file see the below link:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html

Comment: yes looks like PhoneGap Build defualts to Cloud and no option to change via config.xml, may be i need to set it up in local. i will give a try on that

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong the message is quite clear, they just don't want you to upload to their cloud data that is not generated by the user.

I don't know your app, but sounds like are you backing up things like images or media used by the application itself instead of user's data ¿?

Comment: Hi, I'm not backing up any data, even the provisioning file i choose no icloud. all im doing is json data from proxy and displaying to the user.

Comment: so it is a completely 'read-only' app? doesn't even save user data locally?

Comment: yes, its just read only. no local storage at all. its built using sencha touch

Comment: dont know why they are saying 'your app stores non user-generated content in iCloud backup directories'

Comment: yes, that's the problem, may be its because sencha touch store app cache?? any idea?

Comment: suppose that is the problem.. it shouldnt apply because you dont use localstorages, they are all ajax with json reader (I guess)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36273/discussion-between-pavan-and-nico-grunfeld)

Answer (score 0):

@Brett Bailey: Thanks for your input, finally this parameter worked and iTunes approved my app now
https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=687594497&mt=8